# Loop through a list and find certain values VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have a long list of values that are getting longer each day. It contains data from a machine that assign values based on buttons pushed, values are -1, 0, 1, 2.

[image]

Every time the machine is executing an operation, it assign a unique number to it. If the button "test" is pushed, it gives the value -1 and the unique number from the previous operation is assign to this "test". This is because the test does not count as an operation. Example number 331 in picture.

I order to create a report from my data I want it on the format presented below.

[image]

I therefor need a VBA code that will be going through the entire list (about 2000 cells now) and move the values onto a new sheet.

So far, I have tried to copy the area containing the values I need on to a new sheet and then use this formula to move each number.

```
Worksheets("Sheetname").Cells(NewRow + 2, 2).Value = Range("button").Value
```

Comment: So what have you tried? And what is your particular problem?

Answer (score 1):

I hope I understanded the question. The following code may not be the cleanest but it works. I have assumed that start->stop always have the same count of steps and always in the same order.

```
Sub test2()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

For i = 1 To 20000
    For j = 1 To 9
        nextfree = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A:A")) + 1
        If Sheets("sheet1").Range("A" & i).Value = Sheets("sheet2").Cells(1, j).Value Then
            Sheets("sheet2").Cells(nextfree, j).Value = Sheets("sheet1").Range("C" & i).Value
        End If
    Next j
Next i

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Using `Select` like this is cumbersome. Perhaps you could have an array of different cases and then determine the column based on the position of a string in the array?

Comment: @CallumDA  Do you mean like this? See my updated answer.

Comment: Yeah, that's a lot better